# If I remove a div with slideUp than the counter is becoming late by one number

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm learing HTML & JS. For learning purpose I am coding a new ticketing system for my company. Currently I run into a problem which dont know how to fix.

So when I run the script without the slideUp animation the counter counts right but when I insert the animation the counter is one number late.

Example:

```
4 Notifications shown
Counter shows "4"
```

Delete one Notification by clicking on it.

```
3 Notifications shown
Counter shows "4"
```

Delete one Notification by clicking on it.

```
2 Notifications shown
Counter shows "3"
```

And so on.....

Notification Remover:

```
$(function(){
$(document).on('click', '.notification_closebtn_img', function(){
    //Del Notification
    $(this).parents(".notification").slideUp('slow', function(){
        $(this).remove();
    });
    //Placeholder
    if ( $("#notification_center").children().length === 0) 
    {
        $( "#notification_center" ).append('<div id="notification_empty"><div class="notification_empty_text"><strong>Keine Benachrichtigungen vorhanden</strong></div></div>');
    }

    set_ticket_counter();
   });
});
```

Counter:

```
function set_ticket_counter(){
    var notification_counter = $('.notification').length;
    $("#menu_num_text").text(notification_counter);
}
```

Can anyone help me with this?

Thomas Haas

Comment: Animations are async, set your logic in relevant complete callback

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This part of the code:

```
//Placeholder
if ( $("#notification_center").children().length === 0) 
{
    $( "#notification_center" ).append('<div id="notification_empty"><div class="notification_empty_text"><strong>Keine Benachrichtigungen vorhanden</strong></div></div>');
}

set_ticket_counter();
```

will execute before the animations is done. So your counter will be higher by one.

Place the above code in the slideUp callback like this:

```
$(function(){
$(document).on('click', '.notification_closebtn_img', function(){
    //Del Notification
    $(this).parents(".notification").slideUp('slow', function(){
        $(this).remove();
        //Placeholder
        if ( $("#notification_center").children().length === 0) 
        {
            $( "#notification_center" ).append('<div id="notification_empty"><div class="notification_empty_text"><strong>Keine Benachrichtigungen vorhanden</strong></div></div>');
        }

        set_ticket_counter();
    });
   });
});
```

And the counter will be equal to the number of notifications.

Comment: Thanks :) Works fine now!